# Is there a performance difference between setting a field by a method AND setting it by property?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, clr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Actual Performance of Fields vs. Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369346/actual-performance-of-fields-vs-properties)

Is there a known performance difference between setting a field by method AND setting it via property?

(I just wonder if implementing a property emits some extra stuff to IL which makes the PROPERTY work slower than directly callind a method that sets the value)

Comment: Try it! Run both approaches in a loop and time them.

Comment: @Oded: I did :) Now I can see that property seems to be slower

Comment: Nothing beats testing such things by yourself :)

Comment: If there is a performance difference it must be measurable in µs so you should use the more understandable way rather than the most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties **are** methods. If you declare a property named `MyProperty` with both get/set then the compiler will emit two methods: `get_MyProperty` and `set_MyProperty`, decorating them to make understandable to others (who will use the property) that that methods are getter/setter of a property. For example the first version of managed C++ didn't hide this trick. Take a look to decompiled version of a method and a property setter (for example) and you'll see they aren't different, what you see in your code is sugar to make them "nice".